# main関数で初期化したものをhandlerで参照するとnilになる。

Tags: go, redis

現在Goで[RediStore](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/boj/redistore.v1#RediStore.Get)というOSSを使用しています。そのインスタンスである*RediStoreをグローバル変数としてmain関数内で以下のとおり初期化しました。

```
///main関数ない
///var store *rediStore.RediStore//グローバル変数として宣言
    store, err = redistore.NewRediStore(20, "tcp", ":6379", "", []byte("session-key"))

    if store == nil {
      //ここはnilでない
        panic("store is nil")
    }
    if err != nil {
      //エラーもない
        panic(err)
    }
    defer store.Close()
    store.SetMaxAge(259200)
```

そして、user_handlerというhandler内でGetSessionを呼び出すことで下記の通りそのインスタンスを参照しました。しかし、ここで参照したstoreがnilになってしまいます。main関数内でエラーがでていないので初期化は完了しているはずだと考えたのですがなぜでしょうか

```
func GetSession(c *echo.Context) *sessions.Session {
    if c.Request() == nil {
        panic("c is nil")
    }
    if store == nil {
      //nilになっている
        panic("store is nil")
    }
    session, err := store.Get(c.Request(), KeySession)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return session
}
```

エラーは以下のようなものがでました。

```
invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

これは自分でデバッグ用のコードを入れる前のエラーです。

Comment: 念の為確認しますが、`store, err = redistore.NewRediStore(...` 部分の err 変数も宣言済み(例えば `var err error`)ですよね？

Comment: はい｡main関数内で宣言されています｡

Comment: ありがとうございます。それでは main 関数で `if store == nil { ...` よりも先にエラーチェック `if err != nil { ...` を行うとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: たった今試してみましたが変わりはなく、GetSession内のif文でnull pointerがでました。

Comment: お手数をかけまして済みません、また何か分かりましたらコメントします。

Comment: `GetSession()` は `package main` の下の関数ですか? 念のため別のパッケージになってる可能性を考慮しています。

Comment: KoRoN様
すべてmainパッケージ内です。